# Improve my SQL database form PHP code

Tags: php, sql

Can someone have a look at my code Ive finally got working after 2 days and lots of help from here - thank you!

There are a few tweaks i would like to do on it -

- for the transaction ID, if i search for any letter in the transaction id, i am shown records - I only want it to show me a record if the FULL transaction ID has been entered and matches the record in the database. Transaction id example: 87K07228GD157974M
- if you want to retrieve your code, you must type in your name, email and transaction date, this works perfect BUT the time is also included with the date but i don't want anyone to have to enter the time as well ONLY the date i.e.....
  you currently have to enter: 2013-03-07 01:39:23 - but i want to enter in the format of DD/MM/YY - is this possible?

I also don't know if the code is secure also, any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks,

### here is the code:

findme.html

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor=#ffffff>

<h2>Search Transaction ID</h2>

<form name="search" method="post" action="findme.php">
Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> 


<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
OR

<h2>Search Name, E-Mail & Transaction Date</h2>

<form name="search" method="post" action="findme1.php">
Full Name (on paypal account) <input type="text" name="name" /> <br><br>
Paypal E-Mail Address <input type="text" name="email" />  <br><br>
Transaction Date - DD/MM/YY <input type="text" name="date" /> 


<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" /><br><br>
If searching via Name, E-Mail & Transaction date, all fields must be completed to     obtain your code.
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

---

findme.php

```
<html>
<head><title>Searching for a student...</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>

<?php

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($find == "")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}

// Otherwise we connect to our Database
mysql_connect("location.com", "ipn", "password!") or                 die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ipn") or die(mysql_error());

// We perform a bit of filtering
$find = strtoupper($find);
$find = strip_tags($find);
$find = trim ($find);

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ibn_table WHERE itransaction_id LIKE '%$find%'");

//And we display the results
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $iname ))
{
echo "<b>Name: </b>";
echo $result['iname'];
echo " "; 
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>E-mail: </b>";
echo $result['iemail'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Transaction Date: </b>";
echo $result['itransaction_date'];
echo "<br>";
//And we remind them what they searched for
echo "<b>Search Term </b>(Transaction ID): </b> " .$find;
//}
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Login Code: </b>";
echo $result['ipaymentstatus'];
echo "<br>";
}

//This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little     message explaining that
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($iname);
if ($anymatches == 0)
{
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your search, please make sure the     correct details have been entered...<br><br>";
}


?> 


</body>
</html>
```

---

findme1.php

```
<html>
<head><title>Searching for a student...</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ffffff>

<?php

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($name == "")
if ($email == "")
{
echo "<p>Please enter Full Name, E-Mail Address & Transaction Date EXACTLY how they     appear on your PayPal Account...";
exit;
}

// Otherwise we connect to our Database
mysql_connect("location.com", "ipn", "password") or         die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("ipn") or die(mysql_error());

// We perform a bit of filtering
$find = strtoupper($find);
$find = strip_tags($find);
$find = trim ($find);

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
$name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ibn_table WHERE iemail = '$email' AND iname =     '$name' AND itransaction_date = '$date'");

//And we display the results
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $name ))
{
echo "<b>Name: </b>";
echo $result['iname'];
echo " "; 
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>E-mail: </b>";
echo $result['iemail'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Transaction Date: </b>";
echo $result['itransaction_date'];
echo "<br>";
//And we remind them what they searched for
echo "<b>Search Term </b>(Transaction ID): " .$name;
//}
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<b>Login Code: </b>";
echo $result['ipaymentstatus'];
echo "<br>";
}

//This counts the number or results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little     message explaining that
$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($name);
if ($anymatches == 0)
{
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your search, please make sure the     correct details have been entered...<br><br>";
}


?> 


</body>
</html>
```

---

Fields in my database are:

```
iname
iemail
itransaction_id
ipaymentstatus
itransaction_date
```

Thanks!

Comment: Paste snippet where your code is not working or at least locate where the code is malfunctioning.

Comment: code is working in general but i need to tweak the date and when you search for only part of transaction ID - wasnt sure which part to add...

Comment: Please point out those lines.

Comment: transaction id:
$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ibn_table WHERE itransaction_id LIKE '%$find%'");

Comment: and the date side, its in findme1.php but not 100% sure sorry

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comment for transaction ID you have :
`$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ibn_table WHERE itransaction_id LIKE '%$find%'");`

what `LIKE` with `%$find%` does is match any part from transaction ID with `$find` that is why you get results with single letter. Change that to :

```
$iname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ibn_table WHERE itransaction_id = '$find'");
```

for date issue you can decide what to take from user like you stated date then for example :

if you take :

```
$date = "12-11-2012"; //(dd-mm-yyyy)

$split = explode("-", $date);
```

then you can use this to generate SQL date/time format :

```
$sql_date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, (int) $split[1], (int) $split[0], (int) $split[2]))
```

and in sql query :

```
transaction_date LIKE '$sql_date%'
```

And at last don't use `mysql_*` it is deprecated. Instead use `mysqli`.

Comment: Thanks! the transaction id part works perfectly :-)

Not quite sure where to put the info for the date tho? sorry to be a pain